# ¿Porque se actualiza mi navegador al subir un archivo con ajax, jquery y php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

mando los datos por ajax y valido con jquery, después recibo los datos en el php, para subir el `archivo uso copy()` o `move_uploaded_file()` y cuando se sube el archivo se actualiza el navegador y lo que necesito es que se quede una respuesta al subir un archivo y no se actualice, pero al subirse el archivo se actualiza el navegador me pueden ayudar.

código ajax y jquery:

```
        $("#Subir").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var file = $(".archi1")[0].files[0];

            //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
            var fileName = file.name;

            //obtenemos la extensión del archivo
            fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

            if (fileExtension == "txt" || fileExtension == "csv") {
               // if (fileName == 'MOVWEBDEF.txt' || fileName == 'MOVWEBDEF.csv') {
                    //aqui se muestra una imagen y se manda al url que se introduc el archivo .txt o .csv
                    $('#Cargando').css("display", "block");
                    formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "../../ActualizarRegistroCivil/ActualizarDef.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "html",
                        data: formData,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    })
                            .done(function (data) {
                                $("#Respuesta_Tabla").html(data);

                                if (data == 'Vacio') {
                                    document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = false;
                                    document.getElementById("Vacio").style.color = "red";
                                    $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");

                                } else if (data == 'FormatoIncorrecto') {
                                    document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = false;
                                    document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").style.color = "red";
                                    $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");
                                } else if (data == 'Error') {
                                    document.getElementById("Error").hidden = false;
                                    document.getElementById("Error").style.color = "red";
                                    $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");

                                } else {
                                    $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");
                                    document.getElementById("Respuesta_Tabla").hidden = false;
                                }
                            });

               /* } else {
                    document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").hidden = false;
                    document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = true;
                    document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").style.color = "red";
                    document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = true;
                }*/
            } else {

                $("#input01").each(function () {
                    this.value = "";
                });

                $(".form-control").each(function () {
                    this.value = "";
                });
                //mostramos el mjs de error
                document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = false;
                document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = true;

            }

        }
  });
```

php:

```
 $Archivo = $_FILES['archivo1']['name'];
 $NombreArchivoText = $_FILES['archivo1']['tmp_name'];

 if (empty($NombreArchivoText)) {
echo "Vacio";
} else {
if (is_uploaded_file($NombreArchivoText)) {
    $formato = array('.txt', '.csv');
    $ext = substr($Archivo, strrpos($Archivo, '.'));
    if (in_array($ext, $formato)) {
        if ($ext == '.txt') {
            $formatos = '.txt';
        }if ($ext == '.csv') {
            $formatos = '.csv';
        }
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Costa_Rica");
        $fecha = date_default_timezone_get();
        $fecha = date("Y-m-d-H-i-s");
        $NombreArchivo = "MOVWEBDEF" . '_' . $fecha . $formatos;
        $ruta = "../Archivos/Defunciones/" . $Archivo;
        move_uploaded_file($NombreArchivoText, $ruta); // al ejecutar esta linea sucede que el navegador se actualice
        } else {
        echo 'FormatoIncorrecto';
      }
    echo "guardo Archivo";
  } else {
    echo "Error";
   }
}
```

html

```
                  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formulario" method="POST">
                                <label>Subir Archivo extensiones: .txt &oacute; .csv</label>
                                <div id="input1" hidden>
                                    <input type="file" id="input01" class="archi1" name="archivo1" >
                                </div>
                                <div id="input2" hidden>
                                    <input type="file" id="input02" class="archi2" name="archivo2" >
                                </div>
                                <div id="input3" hidden>
                                    <input type="file" id="input03" class="archi3" name="archivo3">
                                </div>
                                <div id="input4" hidden>
                                    <input type="file" id="input04" class="archi4" name="archivo4">
                                </div>
                                <div id="input5" hidden>
                                    <input type="file" id="input05" class="archi5" name="archivo5">
                                </div>

                                <div id="FormatoInvalido" hidden=""> 
                                    <br>
                                    Extensi&oacute;n del archivo incorrecto 
                                </div>

                                <div id="Vacio" hidden=""> 
                                    <br>
                                    Ingrese un archivo .txt &oacute; .csv
                                </div>
                                <div id="Error" hidden=""> 
                                    <br>
                                    El archivo no fue subido por http
                                </div>
                                <div id="ArchivoErroneo" hidden=""> 
                                    <br>
                                    El archivo no pertenece a la categor&iacute;a selecionada
                                </div>

                                <div class="Boton" >
                                    <input name="Subir" id="Subir" class="BotonContinuar" type="button" value="Subir">
                                </div> 
                            </form>
```

Comment: puede ser el tipo de botón html que estas usando <button> , <input type='button'> , <input type='submit'> 

http://www.desarrolloweb.com/articulos/botones-html-etiqueta-button.html

http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=539:formularios-html-botones-envio-submit-restablecimiento-reset-imagen-y-contenido-button-cu00724b&catid=69:tutorial-basico-programador-web-html-desde-cero&Itemid=192

Comment: <input type='button'> eso es lo que me extraña por que nunca hago un submit

Comment: listo ya lo agregue

Comment: Sé que no es la respuesta ideal pero: has probado con event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: lo probé y de igual forma sigue actualizando el navegador

Comment: esto no me gusta  " .done(function (data) { "    y yo creo que podria ser eso, no estas usando bien ajax

Comment: @abrahamhs es correcto usar `.done`, si revisas la documentación de jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ , de hecho .success es considerado Deprecated desde la versión 1.8

Comment: Si es correcto usarlo, pero siento que se pierde la idea del momento en que ocurre cada evento, Yo usuaria success, error y complete dentro del json que se le manda a la función $.ajax (pero es mi particular punto de vista). Eso de success no lo sabia

Comment: igual probé con el success: y tampoco siempre sigue recargando, estuve viendo y se supone que el FormData hace como si fuera un submit, pero no encuentro otra forma de subir archivos asi

Comment: Disculpa pudiste resolverlo sin la necesidad de cambiar de versión de jquery por que yo tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 1):

Prueba colocando

> return false;

```
$("#Subir").on('click', function () 
{
        var file = $(".archi1")[0].files[0];

        //obtenemos el nombre del archivo
        var fileName = file.name;

        //obtenemos la extensión del archivo
        fileExtension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        if (fileExtension == "txt" || fileExtension == "csv") {
           // if (fileName == 'MOVWEBDEF.txt' || fileName == 'MOVWEBDEF.csv') {
                //aqui se muestra una imagen y se manda al url que se introduc el archivo .txt o .csv
                $('#Cargando').css("display", "block");
                formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formulario"));

                $.ajax({
                    url: "../../ActualizarRegistroCivil/ActualizarDef.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
                })
                        .done(function (data) {
                            $("#Respuesta_Tabla").html(data);

                            if (data == 'Vacio') {
                                document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("Vacio").style.color = "red";
                                $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");

                            } else if (data == 'FormatoIncorrecto') {
                                document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").style.color = "red";
                                $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");
                            } else if (data == 'Error') {
                                document.getElementById("Error").hidden = false;
                                document.getElementById("Error").style.color = "red";
                                $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");

                            } else {
                                $('#Cargando').css("display", "none");
                                document.getElementById("Respuesta_Tabla").hidden = false;
                            }
                        });

           /* } else {
                document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").hidden = false;
                document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = true;
                document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").style.color = "red";
                document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = true;
            }*/
        } else {

            $("#input01").each(function () {
                this.value = "";
            });

            $(".form-control").each(function () {
                this.value = "";
            });
            //mostramos el mjs de error
            document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("ArchivoErroneo").hidden = true;
            document.getElementById("FormatoInvalido").style.color = "red";
            document.getElementById("Vacio").hidden = true;

        }

        //Esto hara que no se tenga en cuenta el comportamiento
        //por defecto del boton
        return false;
    }
  });
```

Comment: igual sigue recargando la página, estuve leyendo que el FormData hace como tipo de submit, pero no se si hay otra forma de mandar por ajax un archivo

Comment: ponle la *e* en $("#Subir").on('click', function (e) ..... y donde está el *return false;* ponle *e.preventDefault();*

Comment: e.preventDefault() es mejor llamarlo normalmente al comienzo del handler.

Comment: si yo lo agregue igual no sucede nada siempre recarga la pagina

Answer (score 0):

gracias a los que me ayudaron, ya encontré cual fue el error y no era en el código, era en el html cuando llamaba el javascript ya que el chrome no lo soporta era este código para el que le pase algún dia.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

y al final descargue otro y si lo soporto el chrome

Comment: No entendí, qué estaba mal entonces?

Comment: que el chrome no soporta esa versión de javascript tuve que descargar una version anterior seguro un complemento no lo soporta

Comment: Quieres decir jQuery? o te refieres a ECMAScript?