# Error en funcion ajax al enviar archivo

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy intentando enviar a una api un archivo que tengo en mi pc  Esta es mi función.

```
  $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url:  "https://intes/wsaica/servicioweb/nuo",
          headers: {"Authorization":("Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIbw")},  
         data: {
                "metadata": {"company_id":"A4768","producer_id":"2350F"},
                "files": {type:"file", path:"C:/Users/Agroc/Veeo/cacherun/127.0.0.1/1.pdf"}
          },
         contentType: "x-www.formurlencoded", 
         timeout: 5*60,
          success: function(data, http_status) {    
                alert(data);
          },
          error: function(data, http_status) {
                alert("Error: [uploadFile] "+http_status + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data))
          }
        });
```

Me da el siguiente error: Error: [uploadFile] 400
"{"status":"Error","error_code":"2","error_description":"**Alguno de los valores indicados en el JSON no se corresponde con el formato esperado**"}"

Estoy probando este método:
Sería algo así?

```
 var data;
 data= new FormData();
 data.append( 'files',"C:/Users/o/cun/127.0.0.1/1.pdf"),
 data.append('metadata',{"company_id":"A18","producer_id":"230F"})
   
$.ajax({
        url:"https://integra-servicio.ob.es/wsregsaica/soweb/nueato",
        headers: {"Authorization":("Bearer eyJhbGcFc")},  
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert( data );
        },
         error: function(data, http_status) {
            alert("Error: [uploadFile] "+http_status + "\n" + JSON.stringify(data))
      }
    });
```

Esto me lanza un error como que no puede encontrar la variable formData

Comment: No puedes envíar un archivo indicando la ruta de tu computador, eso equivaldría a que el servidor tuviera acceso al sistema de archivos del cliente.  Debes ingresar el archivo mediante un `input type=file` y luego puedes usar un `formdata` para enviarlo por ajax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Buenas. Gracias por la respuesta. Esto lo hago desde Velneo. Velneo es la plataforma Low Code  con opción de trabajar con JS.  Te importaría pasarme algún ejemplo? Con la documentación no me aclaro mucho. Gracias

Comment: Supongo que esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/8591/301324 se ajusta a lo que necesitas

Comment: Espero que tus credenciales no sean auténticas. Evita publicar credenciales y nombre reales en las preguntas. Esa información podría ser capturada por usuarios mal intencionados que pululan por la red.

Comment: No, las credenciales no son auténticas. Gracias por el aviso.